# Using free() function in recursive function in C

Tags: c, recursion

I have a basic recursive function for traversing the directories.

In the code there are some memory leaks. But I can't find them, I tried `free()` in some lines but, it doesn't work.

There are 6 allocs and and 4 free. How can I make it 6 allocs and 6 free? I think I should `free` the `depthPath`,shouldn't I? (If yes, where should I `free` it?)

This is my c program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h> 

void recursiveFoo (char *path);

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    recursiveFoo (argv[1]);

    return 0; 
}

void recursiveFoo (char *path){
    char *depthPath;
    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *dir;
    d = opendir(path);
    if (d) {
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {   

            depthPath= (char*)malloc(strlen(path) + strlen(dir->d_name) + 1);
            strcpy(depthPath, path);
            strcat(depthPath, "/");
            strcat(depthPath, dir->d_name);


            if(((strcmp(dir->d_name,".")!=0) && (strcmp(dir->d_name,".."))!=0) ){
                recursiveFoo(depthPath);   
                free(depthPath); 
            }

        }

        printf("%s/",path );

        closedir(d);
    }
}
```

And after compiling with `-ggdb3`,this is my Valgrind output:

```
   ==641== HEAP SUMMARY:
==641==     in use at exit: 13 bytes in 2 blocks
==641==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 4 frees, 33,876 bytes allocated
==641== 
==641== Searching for pointers to 2 not-freed blocks
==641== Checked 62,760 bytes
==641== 
==641== 13 bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==641==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==641==    by 0x400839: recursiveFoo (stack.c:29)
==641==    by 0x4007D7: main (stack.c:14)
==641== 
==641== LEAK SUMMARY:
==641==    definitely lost: 13 bytes in 2 blocks
==641==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==641==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==641==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==641==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==641== 
==641== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==641== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: I would definitely focus on the errors before the reported leak. Those errors describe invalid pointer uses, which are undefined behavior and might also be messing with the memory tracking.

Comment: Hint: use `s(n)printf` instead of `strcat` stuff...

Comment: as for the `free`, free the path the earliest when it is no longer needed! (and where it is needed is in the recursive function call!)

Comment: Your code crashes when I try it in a directory with lots of different-sized files. You got lucky with your directory that has only 4 files?

Comment: The leak is trivially fixed  - `free()` is currently called in the body of an `if` statement, which means allocated memory is not released unless the body of the `if` is executed.    Move the `free()` to AFTER the if block.   That way, if `malloc()` is called, the corresponding `free()` will ALWAYS be called, not sometimes.   Your code has a couple of "smells" so I would not be surprised if there are other logic errors, but I'll leave it there.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be appending the `.`. and `..` directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code doesn't allocate enough memory for the string copied into the block:

```
        depthPath= (char*)malloc(strlen(path) + strlen(dir->d_name) + 1);
        strcpy(depthPath, path);
        strcat(depthPath, "/");
        strcat(depthPath, dir->d_name);
```

The new string requires `strlen(path) + strlen(dir->d_name) + strlen( "/" ) + 1` characters to account for both the `"/"` **and** the terminating `'\0'`.

Also, to fix your leak, this code

```
    while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {   

        depthPath= (char*)malloc(strlen(path) + strlen(dir->d_name) + 1);
        strcpy(depthPath, path);
        strcat(depthPath, "/");
        strcat(depthPath, dir->d_name);


        if(((strcmp(dir->d_name,".")!=0) && (strcmp(dir->d_name,".."))!=0) ){
            recursiveFoo(depthPath);   
        }

    }
```

can be written as

```
    while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
    {   
        if(((strcmp(dir->d_name,".")==0) ||
            (strcmp(dir->d_name,".."))==0) )
        {
            continue;
        }

        char *depthPath= malloc(strlen(path) + strlen(dir->d_name) + 2);
        strcpy(depthPath, path);
        strcat(depthPath, "/");
        strcat(depthPath, dir->d_name);

        recursiveFoo(depthPath);   

        free(depthPath):
    }
```

Comment: Okay , the error decrease to 1, I updated the question.Could you look that?

Answer (score 1):

You do not allocate enough memory for `depthPath`:

```
        depthPath= (char*)malloc(strlen(path) + strlen(dir->d_name) + 1);
        strcpy(depthPath, path);
        strcat(depthPath, "/");
        strcat(depthPath, dir->d_name);
```

The resulting string needs an extra byte for the `\0` that will be at the end.

To fix the memory leak, you can add `free(depthPath);` to the bottom of the loop, just before going to the next iteration.

Alternatively, you can modify your code to use `realloc()` instead of `malloc()`, and then call `free()` after the loop completes. You will likely want to initialize `depthPath` to `NULL` when trying this approach.

The algorithm allocates *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* memory as you recurse deeper into the directory tree. To avoid that, you can modify your approach so that your `path` argument is itself passed to *realloc()* to make room for the additional subdirectory. However, since *realloc()* may return a different pointer value than the one passed into it, the pointer value needs to come back to the caller.

To maintain the original API usage, then actual recursive function with `realloc()` calls can be encapsulated into a helper function.

```
static void recursiveFoo__(char **, int);

void recursiveFoo (const char *path) {
    int depthPathLen = strlen(path);
    char *depthPath = malloc(depthPathLen+1);
    strcpy(depthPath, path);
    recursiveFoo__(&depthPath, depthPathLen);
    free(depthPath);
}

void recursiveFoo__ (char **depthPath, int depthPathLen){
    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *dir;
    d = opendir(*depthPath);
    if (d) {
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {   
            int newPathLen = depthPathLen + strlen(dir->d_name) + 1;
            char *newPath= realloc(*depthPath, newPathLen+1);
            if (newPath == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "oops: %.*s/%s\n",
                        depthPathLen, *depthPath, dir->d_name);
                break;
            }
            *depthPath = newPath;
            strcpy(newPath+depthPathLen, "/");
            strcpy(newPath+depthPathLen+1, dir->d_name);
            if(((strcmp(dir->d_name,".")!=0) &&
                (strcmp(dir->d_name,".."))!=0) ){
                recursiveFoo__(depthPath, newPathLen);   
            }
        }
        printf("%.*s/\n", depthPathLen, *depthPath);
        closedir(d);
    }
}
```

Now, the memory allocation will be *O(n)*.

Comment: Okay , the error decrease to 1, I updated the question.Could you look that?

Comment: That's the leak. Free `depthPath` after your recursive call returns.

Comment: I edited again, still I have 1 error.

Comment: Okay, it's hard to keep up with your edits. Move the free call after the `if`, before your loop ends.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot, it worked.

Comment: Could you explain , why it doesn't work in the if block? (I think that It should be work becasue , only recursive function can call in the if block)?

Comment: Because your code always allocates the memory, even when you don't want to do the recursive call. So you need to always free it, even when you didn't make the recursive call.

Comment: Okay , now I understand that. Thanks a lot.